# JavaScript change input text to select option

Tags: javascript, html, select, input, element

Is it possible to change element on page from input text field to select option element with JavaScript?

I want customize some page with `greasemonkey`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried yet?

Comment: Yes; there's a ton of ways to do this. SO isn't really for specific implementation problems. Go and try to implement it yourself, then come back with a more specific problem.

Comment: No, it's not possible, you can't change an elements tagName, but you could just replace it with another element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to identify the form and the input element (by either the name or ID). You'll need to create the new `select` element, create and add as many `option` elements to it as you wish, and finally insert it in the place of the existing text input element.

You could, for example, use something like this:

```
// ** change 'form' and 'text' to correctly identify the form and text input element **
var inputElement = document.forms['form'].elements['text'];
var selectElement = document.createElement('select');

// get the existing input element's current (or initial) value
var currentValue = inputElement.value || inputElement.getAttribute('value');

// add a list of options to the new select element
// ** change value/text and add/remove options as needed **
var options = [{value: 'option1', text: 'Option 1'},
               {value: 'option2', text: 'Option 2'},
               {value: 'option3', text: 'Option 3'}];

options.forEach(function (option, i) {
    var optionElement = document.createElement('option');
    optionElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(option.text));
    optionElement.setAttribute('value', option.value);
    selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);

    // if the option matches the existing input's value, select it
    if (option.value == currentValue) {
        selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
    }
});

// copy the existing input element's attributes to the new select element
for (var i = 0; i < inputElement.attributes.length; ++ i) {
    var attribute = inputElement.attributes[i];

    // type and value don't apply, so skip them
    // ** you might also want to skip style, or others -- modify as needed **
    if (attribute.name != 'type' && attribute.name != 'value') {
        selectElement.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    }
}

// finally, replace the old input element with the new select element
inputElement.parentElement.replaceChild(selectElement, inputElement);
```

If it's an ordinary form element without much scripting attached to it already, it's fairly simple. However, note that if there were any script events attached to the text element (focus, change, blur, etc.), those will not work anymore. If you want the select element to have similar script events, you'll need to re-write those events to apply to it instead.

The new `select` element will probably also be a different size/style than the original `input` element was; you could add more code to change the style of the new element if you don't like the default appearance.